# Word norm in compact subsets of finitely generated groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, topological-groups, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated topological group, not necessarily discrete. Fix a finite generating set $S$ and denote by $|x|$ the word norm of $x \in G$ with respect to this generating set, i.e., the minimal $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there exist $s_1, \ldots, s_n \in S$ with $x = s_1 \cdots s_n$. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $G$. Is it true that $\{ |k| : k \in K \} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is bounded?

Comment: Can you please provide the definition of "word norm"?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Of course no: bounded subsets are finite, while if $G$ is metrizable and nondiscrete there are infinite compact subsets.

Comment: @YCor Right: I missed the fact that bounded sets are finite. Thanks! Also, I should add that this counterexample is very general: if the identity of a group is closed then the group is automatically regular, and if furthermore it is finitely generated then it is (second-)countable, so is metrizable by Urisohn

Comment: @user404944 beware that countable does not imply second-countable. For instance, the Bohr topology on $\mathbf{Z}$ is not second-countable, and not metrizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, no.

Pick $G=\mathbb{Z}$, $S=\{ 1 \}$, but endow $G$ with the $p$-adic topology (for example $p=2$).
Then $K=\{p^k\}_{k \geq 0} \cup \{0\}$ is a converging sequence and its endpoint, so is a compact subset, and clearly the lengths are not bounded on $K$.

Comment: Great, that's what I imagined. Just one more question, is $\mathbb{Z}$ locally compact with the $p$-adic topology? I know the definition but I am not that familiar with it...

Comment: It is not locally compact; I think a countable group cannot be locally compact unless the topology is discrete, it has to do with perfect sets being uncountable...

Comment: @user120527 or Baire's theorem